# How to use xpath or query to extract data from xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xquery

I have a xml file look like

```
<info>

  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">10.1.2.118</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">50118</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">10.1.2.119</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">50118</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">10.1.2.120</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">50118</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">10.1.2.157</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">50118</Data> 


</info>
```

i need extract the data node with ***name*** attribute value =**"Ipaddress"** and Node value =**10.1.2.157**, how i can use this using any xml querying techniques

Comment: What have you tried?  And you say XPath then say 'any xml querying techniques' - so do you want XPath for a reason or is that choice entirely arbitrary?  What do you want to do with the node once extracted (given your query knows all the data relating to it!)?

Comment: @charles mager , lets say i need a  string from this xml file whose attribute value 'IpAddress' and node value=10.1.2.157

Comment: 'Lets say'?  What string?  It's not clear what you're asking or what your end result is, and it looks like you've put no effort into solving this yourself first.  Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Charles mager, just check how  got the answer from Matt Jones.. he clearly understood what the question and what required. thanks

Comment: The answer involves making assumptions and has nothing to do with `c#` or `.net` which is how you've tagged your question.  Just because you got what you wanted doesn't mean the question is clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using XPath, How do I select a node based on its text content and value of an attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982624/using-xpath-how-do-i-select-a-node-based-on-its-text-content-and-value-of-an-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that XML is your entire document, then the following XPath should select the `Data` element that you require:

```
./info/Data[@Name='IpAddress'][.='10.1.2.157']
```

The `./info/Data` will match child nodes of `info` that are named `Data` and the `[@Name='IpAddress'][.='10.1.2.157']` contains two predicates - one to match the `Name` attribute to have a value of "IpAddress" and the other to match the element's content as you have specified.